# How to show tabs based on user permissions in angular4?

Tags: angular

I have an application that shows some data to the user after login. Once the user login, a dashboard is rendered, that contains some pie-charts, line-charts and tabular-data.

Dashboard contains 5 different tabs and currently all the tabs are available at dashboard. Now as per the latest requirement, I need to show only particular tabs that the user is permitted to see.

All the tabs are individual angular components. Now I want to implement it in a way such that if the user don't have permission for 2 tabs, then on dashboard only 3 tabs should be displayed?

I have all the information regarding user after login for user roles and permissions.

I need help on what kind of approach should I follow?

Comment: You can use `*ngIf="somecondtion"`

Comment: I think ngIf will not stop loading of the unauthorized components, or will it?

Comment: Your component won't be loaded until the condition is met

Comment: will check this and get back...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it with *ngIf

```
<tab1 *ngIf="isAdmin"></tab1>
<tab2 *ngIf="!isAdmin"></tab2>
<tab3 *ngIf="isKeyUser"></tab3>
```

and in your component you set these variables depending on the user that currently is logged in.

```
private isAdmin: boolean = false;
private isKeyUser: boolean = false;

private setRoles(): void {
   if(this.user.role === 'admin'){
      this.isAdmin = true; 

      [...]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for something like [Auth guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards). You can implement a service, which is able to determine the permissions of the user and the guard can use the service to disable and enable the tabs (or maybe use ngif to stop the rendering of the tab with missing permissions). The router feature could use for rendering the tabs bar.

I'll hope that could help you.

Comment: Can auth guards hide the tabs? Not sure as I am bit new to angular. AFAIK, auth guards can prevent the navigation to unauthorized page but I don't even want to load it at first place.

Comment: No you cant use auth guards for this situation